# getting 'DevTools failed to parse SourceMap' error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I am getting error : 'DevTools failed to parse SourceMap:'. Any solution for this. I have no clue how to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Vue.js? If so, you might need to install this: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools

If you're using WebEssentials, you might want to look at this as well:

[Google Chrome "Failed parsing SourceMap" : css.map (Web Essential)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36133715/google-chrome-failed-parsing-sourcemap-css-map-web-essential)

Answer (score 1):

If you get this type of error:

> "DevTools failed to parse SourceMap:../js/popper.min.js.map"

or something like this, then go to Developer Tools -> Settings and untick

1. "*Enable JavaScript source maps*"
2. "*Enable CSS source maps*"

[image: example]

Comment: Actually you need to go into Dev Tools settings and you will see the above options. It was very frustrating to search this in the Browser settings!

Comment: It doesn't fix the warnings, just hides it. Mozilla has some more information about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/Source_map_errors.

Answer (score 1):

I received this error:

`DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.preload.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

Then i went to my chrome extensions on chrome://extensions/

and found an extension with the code 'gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom' on my case.

Then i turned it off.

If you want to keep the extension working you can just filter this message on DevTools as in:

[image: Dev tools filter image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If they are just unimportant warnings that are bothering you when leaving the console, you can temporarily disable them (menu option accessed via F12 key):

[image]

Comment: Image is nice, but could add a text description on how to access the menu?

Comment: Oh, yes! F12 key. ;) Thank you!