# expressjs middleware firing twice

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to restrict all pages if the user is not authenticated.

The strange thing is that my middleware is being called twice when I call the login page.

THe following are my code

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.session.user) {
        res.session.user = req.session.user;
    }
    if (req.isAuthenticated() || req.path === '/' || req.path === '/login'){
        console.log('inside next');
        next()
    }else{
        console.log('inside redirect');
        res.redirect('/')
    }
});
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    console.log('inside /')

    res.render('./login', {
        css: ['login.css'],
        js: ['login.js']
    })
});
```

When I go to `localhost:8000/` which is my root page, it prints out following in the console

```
inside next
inside /
inside redirect
inside next
inside /
```

As you can see after `get('/')` is called, the middleware is called once again to redirect the page. Why is this? If I remove the middleware, `/` gets called only once.

Comment: How are you calling the service. Might be something to do with the client code.

Comment: @SamuelToh what do you mean? which part of the code would you like to see

Comment: @SamuelToh as I have said, / gets rendered twice only when I add the middleware so I am guessing it's to do with that.

Comment: The client side javascript which calls `/` and `/login`. Maybe your `login` page is making a call to the `/login` endpoint upon page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why...

Apparently Chrome recently added a support for source map [ESRI : Failed to parse source map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051891/esri-failed-to-parse-source-map)

since the source map was not included in my `vendor` folder, it could not find the source map and refreshed the page.

So from now gotta take caution when copying bootstrap files - copy the source maps with the `css` file so that it doesn't refresh twice