# Website is Missing parts on Hosting server but working perfectly on localhost

Tags: javascript, css, web, twitter-bootstrap-3

my website  https://riyasewena.com is missing some parts after transfering files from local server. But site on localhost works perfectly.

DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: https://riyasewena.com/assets/js/bootstrap-select.js.map this is the error shows in the console. This error message is not showing in localhost.

Styles should appear in the website. But styles and some content is missing in the website.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ESRI : Failed to parse source map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051891/esri-failed-to-parse-source-map)

Comment: @KoenHollander  I have disabled source map loading. Now missing contents are loading. Will this not affect to the client's web browsers?

Comment: are there any errors in the console?