# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0", source: devtools://devtools/bundled/shell.js

Tags: node.js, express, electron

I want to make a desktop app using Electron.js and Express.js

when it was first loaded i got a warning like this:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0", source:
>   devtools://devtools/bundled/shell.js

Is there something wrong with my code ?

and in developer console has a warning like this:

[image: WARNING]

**Server.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import path from 'path';
import cors from 'cors'
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

(function(){
    app.use(cors())
    app.use(express.static('public'));

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/index.html'));
    })

    app.listen(PORT, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(`Server is Running on PORT : ${PORT}`)
        }
    })
})();
```

**Electron**

```
const electron = require('electron');
const server = require('./server')
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
    mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:5000');
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        mainWindow = null
    })
}
app.on('ready', createWindow);
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
});

app.on('activate', function () {
    if (mainWindow === null) {
        createWindow()
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ESRI : Failed to parse source map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051891/esri-failed-to-parse-source-map)

Comment: It is often helpful to search on the error message to see if others have encountered the same error. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051891/esri-failed-to-parse-source-map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use quick start app officially provided in the [electron website](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app#trying-this-example)

Direct github url is provided in the link

Otherwise download demo apps from officially provided in the [electron demo apps](https://electronjs.org/#get-started)