# Error laravel project with a blade SourceMap

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a laravel project with a blade, and it worked perfectly, and overnight, it stopped working with this error:

```
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/js/html2canvas.js.map
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css.map
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/css/metisMenu.css.map
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/js/popper.min.js.map
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js.map
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/js/metisMenu.min.js.map
```

my JavaScript files are called normally in blade with:

```
{{URL::asset('assets/js/html2canvas.js')}}
```

The default view of laravel has no errors... I've tested it on windows and macos, and also on shared hosting, the same error happens.

Comment: I'm guessing you're always testing in Chrome and not another browser. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051891/esri-failed-to-parse-source-map

Comment: yes, i use chrome to test, but the same error happens in firefox.
I've cleaned up caches and returned some versions of git, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: just a wild guess .. have you tried adding a **/** at the beginning of the string? as in {{URL::asset('/assets/js/html2canvas.js')}}

Comment: Those errors really shouldn't stop your site from working. Are you seeing any other errors anywhere?

Comment: Are you using an assets build process? Did you build to production?

Comment: that was the solution, but I had some problems debugging a js script so I needed to solve it. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051891/esri-failed-to-parse-source-map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that was the solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051891/esri-failed-to-parse-source-map), but I had some problems debugging a js script so I needed to solve it.

Thank you all for your help!