# laravel 404 (Not Found)

Tags: laravel, botman

how to solve that issue, please? I have created a website then after inserting records in the database with images, then those images are not displaying as I want.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ov7phzh1v636d95/pages.PNG?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/preview/My%20PC%20%28Mupenzi-Furaha%29/Pictures/page.PNG

errors are:

DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/bootstrap.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

In my case

Delete /*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.min.css.map */ in css/bootstrap.min.css

and delete /*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.css.map */ in css/bootstrap.css

sc: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/css/DevTools+failed+to+load+SourceMap%3A+Could+not+load+content+for+bootstrap.min.css.map

Comment: Please i didn't use any of thèse bootstrap, but the problem persist

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051891/esri-failed-to-parse-source-map

Comment: I went into my project in the public folder and in the css where i tried to delete those bootstrap and the output destroyed or gave a desorded the website

Comment: do you use any extensions?

Comment: yes, I use them, but I try to disable those extensions it still the same error.